# Summing elements of a 3d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 3d, sum

Im trying to sum the elements of a 3d array in C. The code recognizes that position check[1][1][0]=4 and adds 4 to sum when the loop reaches this position. However for the rest of the array it continues to add on this value again, and then it adds the total sum again for the rest of the positions of the array. Can anyone see why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int check[3][3][3]={ 0 };
    int size=2;
    int i,j,k,sum=0;

    check[1][1][0]=12;

        for(k=0;k<size;k++) {
            for(j=0;j<size;j++) {
                for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                    printf("i=%d, j=%d,k=%d, checkijk=%d  ",i,j,k,check[i][j][k]);
                    sum+=sum+check[i][j][k];
                    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
                }
            }
        }
printf("The sum is %d\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: "*The code recognizes that position `check[1][1][0]=4` ...*" Did you mean `check[1][1][0]=12`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sum+=sum+check[i][j][k];
```

should be

```
sum+=check[k][j][i];
```

And if you want to sum all the values `int size = 2;` must be `int size = 3;`

Comment: Thankyou, sorry for the unclear question. Was a careless mistake by me.